# Temperature of an Earthlike planet in Mars location?

Tags: science-based, planets, atmosphere, temperature

In the future, Mars has been successfully terraformed to be Earth-like in terms of atmosphere so that humans can inhabit it safely. If Mars had an atmosphere similar to Earth, but was still 1.52 AUs away from the sun, what would its temperature range be? Considering its distance from the Sun, I assume it won't be nearly as warm, and it already gets fairly cold there in the modern day. Would it be actively habitable for humans without suits or outside of a sealed area?

Comment: If this is science based then Mars cannot have a sustainable atmosphere the same as Earths

Comment: @Kilisi you're right when it comes to geological timespans, but on the short term perhaps humans are able to replenish the yearly atmospheric losses. I believe we've had questions about that and the conclusion was that it would take maybe centuries for the losses to become significant.

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw I see your point, but I would think that it would take a very different atmosphere to Earths

Comment: Much better off just building enclosed habitats as big as you want, including farm land, parks, etc. Even leaving aside the (probably unattainable) energy requirements to cook oxygen out of rock, we're talking about excavating a volume or rock big enough to cover Western Europe a meter deep (around 10^19kg) just to have something to make the air out of in the first place, and that's assuming all that volatile oxygen doesn't react with the rocks again over the thousands of years it's going to take you to do it.

Comment: And once you get an atmosphere, it'll be a miserable atmosphere that nobody likes anyway - high maintenance, borderline toxic CO2 levels to keep the temperature up, barely enough O2 to breathe, no water or nitrogen for plants, and not enough pressure to make coffee.

Comment: What about the water? You can't have an Earth-like atmosphere unless you have Earth-like bodies of water and an evaporation cycle. Does your Mars have oceans? That will affect its albedo if it does. Does it have clouds? Also affects the albedo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When sunlight hits a planet, a fraction "a" reflects off the planet, with the rest, (1-a), being absorbed. a is the albedo of the planet. For Earth, the effective albedo is 0.3. Half of that is due to cloud cover.

Then, the warmth of the planet produces long-wavelength photons. The power of these photons is [proportional to T^4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_equilibrium_temperature#Calculation_of_equilibrium_temperature), with T being the planet's temperature in Kelvin. Most of the long-wavelength photons get absorbed by the atmosphere on the way up (greenhouse effect).

In equilibrium, energy in = energy out. For Earth, energy in = 1361 W/m^2, and Earth has an average surface temperature of 288 K. So we have:

1361 W/m^2 = .3 * 1361 W/m^2 + C * (288 K)^4

where C is some constant that accounts for how much heat is emitted by the planet without being trapped by the greenhouse effect. Solving for C on Earth:

C = .7 * 1361 W/m^2 / (288 K)^4 = 1.3848e-7 W/(m^2 K^4)

Now we want to set up the same equation for Mars, using the C from Earth to represent the size of Earth's greenhouse effect. First, what albedo should we use? We want to know what albedo Mars *would* have, if it had an "earth-like" atmosphere.

You didn't say anything about Mars having oceans, so let's suppose that it doesn't have an Earth-like water cycle. That means no oceans and no clouds. That's important; without clouds to reflect light, Earth's albedo would be only half as large.

Mars' current albedo is 0.25. If it had an Earth-like atmosphere, some percentage of incoming sunlight would be absorbed by the atmosphere, lowering the albedo. For Earth, that figure is [23%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenhouse_effect), but our Mars atmosphere lacks clouds so it would be a different amount. But we can't really calculate that, so let's just say Mars-with-atmosphere's albedo is just 0.25 * 0.77 = 0.18.

Mars receives 586 W/m^2 from the sun. So we can set up the equation:

586 W/m^2 = 0.18 * 586 W/m^2 + 1.3848e-7 W/(m^2 K^4) * T^4

Solve for T:

T = (0.82 * 586 W/m^2 / (1.3848e-7 W/(m^2 K^4)))^0.25

= 243 K

or -30 C, or -22.8 F. Pretty cold!

For a sanity check, Earth's temperature without the greenhouse effect would be -20C, and Earth's temperature with the greenhouse effect is 15C, a difference of 35C. Mars' actual temperature without the greenhouse effect is -60C, so our prediction is it would warm by 30C, which is similar to Earth. The simple method we used is probably in the right ballpark.

But note that if you want it to be warmer all you have to do is increase the amount of greenhouse gases. You could make Mars an unlivable 100C if you wanted to, with enough greenhouse gases. You can really choose any temperature you want.

Implicitly here I am assuming an "Earth-like" atmosphere means an "Earth-like" greenhouse effect per m^2. Although this assumption may be questionable because to get 1 bar of pressure at ground level on Mars, you need 2.6 times more mass of air per m^2 due to the lower gravity, so the greenhouse effect would actually be larger with the same composition and ground level pressure. C would be 2.6 times smaller, which would result in an average temperature of (0.82 * 586 W/m^2 / (1.3848e-7 W/(m^2 K^4) / 2.6))^0.25 = 35C. Quite warm! But realistic Mars terraforming involves lower atmospheric pressure than Earth, and again, you can set any temperature you want by adjusting the amount of greenhouse gases.

Comment: Quick question. If Mars had not only the atmosphere of Earth, but the volume of Earth as well (or to make things simpler, Mars was replaced with a copy of current Earth), would your calculations be any different?

Comment: @Rhymehouse They would be the same, because they are about power per m^2, which is independent of how many m^2 you have. Implicitly here I am assuming an "Earth-like" atmosphere means an "Earth-like" greenhouse effect per m^2. Although this assumption may be questionable because to get 1 bar of pressure at ground level on Mars, you need a larger mass of air per m^2 due to the lower gravity, so the greenhouse effect would actually be larger with the same composition and ground level pressure. But it all depends on greenhouse gas composition, and realistic Mars terraforming involves lower bar.

Answer (score 2):

If Mars had an atmosphere similar to the Earth then the planet would exist in a state far beyond it's equilibrium point and a range of different processes would transform it over a range of different time scales.

In the very short term there would be atmospheric chaos with almost all of the water vapor from the Earth like atmosphere condensing into frost or snow. The atmosphere would also probably become thick with the very fine Martian dust stirred up as weak vaguely Earth like winds replaced the ghostly winds of Mars that we know.

In the mid term the average temperature would increase from -60 towards 0 degrees C. Due to increased heat capacity of the atmosphere and vast amounts of dry ice that would permanently out gas from the Martian polar caps.

Eventually this would probably allow large quantities of salt water to exist on the surface again, as was thought to have happened billions of years ago on Mars. It is estimated that there are five million cubic kilometres of water ice on mars today.

Temperatures at the Poles would probably remain very low despite the warming effect of convection currents in the atmosphere and the extra carbon dioxide, so it’s hard to say how much liquid water might remain. It is possible that it might all eventually end up frozen at the poles. Else where there might be areas of freezing shallow seas and/or deep mud with a frozen crust.

Longer term the dust storms would die down in the wetter environment, but details of what would happen depend on what plans you had for the new Mars. If Mars is simply equipped with an Earthly atmosphere and left then oxygen levels would very slowly decline due to the oxidation of surface materials such as meteoric iron and more. With liquid water, freeze/thaw action and vastly more wind present erosion could slowly uncover further materials for oxidation from deeper down leading to depletion of oxygen.

So long term oxygen levels would probably need to be topped up. If a biosphere was created this might well be sufficient for this purpose. Although given the magic involved in creating the Earth like atmosphere in the first place, topping up the oxygen occasionally should not be a problem.

UV dissociation of water in the upper atmosphere into hydrogen and oxygen and subsequent loss of hydrogen to space would slowly rob Mars of its waters, but the process would be extremely slow indeed with the new atmosphere. It took hundreds of millions of years for Mars to lose a large part of it’s liquid water in the past in an oxygen free carbon dioxide atmosphere. The loss of hydrogen would be seriously inhibited by a high concentration of atmospheric oxygen which would tend to react readily with the hydrogen to reform water before its eventual escape. (see “Oxygen – the molecule that made the world” by Nick Lane pages 25-26)

https://zenodo.org/records/1233311